# How can I know/set the HTML that will be rendered with ReactJS?

Tags: html, reactjs

So normally we have these codes as the entry point for ReactJS.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

For the `ReactDOM.render()` how and where I can specify the HTML file? Let say, I want to have the output HTML to be "not_index.html". How can I achieve that? I still don't understand how can ReactJS feels suddenly connected to a HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have a html file that loads this javascript. Somewhere in the html file you have an element with an id of `container`. You don't specify a html file anywhere, you just load that html file with the relevant javascript.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand know. I was thinking the other way around. I thought, I would pick the HTML file in a JavaScript file rendered with ReactJS. Thanks!